# Excel VBA - ShowAllData of table fails

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, excel-tables

I have this longer piece of VBA (see also my former question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206850/copy-rows-which-match-criteria-into-two-or-more-different-sheets-in-excel-with-v)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206850/copy-rows-which-match-criteria-into-two-or-more-different-sheets-in-excel-with-v).

One particular piece doesn't work properly. I want a table to **ShowAllData** as soon as its former actions from the module have been taken.
This code I made so far, **works fine** as long as I **run** it when I'm **from one of the cells of the table**. As soon as I run it **from another place on the worksheet**, it **won't show all data again**. It keeps hanging in the filtermode of the table.

```
   Sub CopyOrders()

'Sorting column STOCK in ORDERS from A-Z
    Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects("Orders").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects("Orders").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Orders[[#All],[STOCK]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects("Orders").Sort
        .Apply
    End With

'Delete all rows from table NoStockOrders
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("NoStockOrders").ListObjects("NoStockOrders").DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete

'Copy all orders which have no stock to
'the sheet NoStockOrders
Worksheets("Orders").Range("ORDERS").AutoFilter _
    Field:=6, Criteria1:="0", VisibleDropDown:=True
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Orders").Range("ORDERS").SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Range("NoStockOrders").PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues

If Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects("Orders").FilterMode Then
    Worksheets("Orders").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects("Orders").Autofilter.showalldata
```

Comment: YES! Works fine!! Thanks Rory!

Answer (score 2):

It can be like that:

```
    With Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects("Orders")
         If Not .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
```

Comment: To align with the code in the original question, shouldn't your first line of code be `With Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects("Orders")` ... then there is no need to rely on `ActiveSheet` being `Worksheets("Orders")` (which can't be guaranteed) and there is no need to change the table (ListObject) number?

Comment: This depends on the situation when programming. 

When programming with many sheets, it's better to mention the sheet's name and the name or number of the table.
`Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects("Orders")`
           or
`Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects(1)`

But if you use only one sheet, you can use the `Activesheet("sheetname")` and the name or number of the table.
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Orders")`
           or
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)`

In general, the result is the same overall.

Comment: My points is that in the original question, the code uses `Worksheets("Orders").ListObjects("Orders")` which is **guaranteed** to return the correct table whereas all the other options you have listed **might** return the correct table. As the questioner already has that valid code, there is no point in changing it.

Comment: You are right, I modified the code, thank you.